# How to create an array entry with ObjectId and Number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and am trying to make this type of entry:

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "resource": {
                "_id": "61be82b9549b4ede0c8df07e"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my schema code:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  resources: [
    {
      amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      resource: {
        _id: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Resource"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

here is the json code i send

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "resource": {
                "_id": "61be82b9549b4ede0c8df07e"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After processing the request, the following entry is created

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "resource": {
                "_id": "61be82b9549b4ede0c8df07e"
            },
            "_id": "61ebf5d2e47442bd566fe157"
        }
    ],
    "_id": "61ebf5d2e47442bd566fe156",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Id for the resource was created correctly, but I can't figure out where the resources._id key came from? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: can you share the mongo query ??

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya, this?
`async create({ body }, res) {
    const item = new model(body);
    const newItem = await item.save();
    return res.status(200).send(newItem);
  }`

Comment: `resources._id` generate automatically from the mongodb. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to off `_id` from schema declaration in the array, after updating schema try inserting new document,

```
const schema = new Schema({
  resources: [
    {
      _id: false, 
      amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      resource: {
        _id: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Resource"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```